# A question on atoms in measure theory.

Tags: measure-theory

The definition in Bogachev's book goes as follows:

> Now let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $\sigma$ algebra and let $\mu$ be a finite countably additive measure. **1.12.7 Definition.** The set $A\in \mathcal{A}$ is called an atom of the measure $\mu$ if $\mu(A)>0$ and every $B\subset A$ from $\mathcal{A}$ has measure either $0$ or $\mu(A)$.

Now, here's where I am stuck:

> If two atoms $A_1,A_2$ are distinct in the sense that $d(A,B)=\mu(A\Delta B)>0$, then $\mu(A_1\cap A_2)=0$.

How to show this claim?

If $\mu(A_1\cap A_2)> 0$ then because $A_1,A_2$ are atoms $\mu(A_1),\mu(A_2)>0$ and $\mu(A_1)=\mu(A_2)=\mu(A_1\cap A_2)$.

Now, $\mu(A_1\Delta A_2) = \mu(A_1\setminus A_2) + \mu(A_2 \setminus A_1)$.
Since $A_1 \setminus A_2 \subset A_1 , A_2 \setminus A_1 \subset A_2$ either:
$\mu(A_1 \setminus A_2)=\mu(A_1)=\mu(A_2) = \mu(A_2\setminus A_1)$ or $\mu(A_1\setminus A_2) = \mu(A_2\setminus A_1) = 0$.

In the latter case we have $d(A_1,A_2)=0$ contrary to the assumption; and if the former case then I am not sure what to contradict here? any suggestions? or hints?

Thanks.

Comment: If you do not restrict to atoms of FINITE measure then  the result is FALSE. Here is a trivial example. Define $\mu$ on $P(\mathbb{N})$ by $\mu(E) =\infty$ if $\{1,2\} \cap E\neq\emptyset$.  and $\mu(E) =0$ if $\{1,2\} \cap E=\emptyset$. It is easy to prove that $\mu$ is a measure. 
Let $A_1=\{1,2\}$ and $A_2=\{2\}$. It is easy to check that both $A_1$ and $A_2$ are atoms and have inifinite measure. Also 
$$\mu(A_1 \Delta  A_2) =\mu(\{1\})=+\infty>0$$ 
and $$\mu(A_1 \cap  A_2) =\mu(\{2\})=+\infty>0$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\mu(A_1\Delta A_2)>0$ implies that at least one of $\mu(A_1 \setminus A_2)=\mu(A_1)$ or $\mu(A_2 \setminus A_1)=\mu(A_2)$ since $A_1$ and $A_2$ are atoms. WLOG assume that $\mu(A_1 \setminus A_2)=\mu(A_1)$.

$\mu(A_1)=\mu(A_1 \setminus A_2)+\mu(A_1 \cap A_2)$ by the additivity of measure, so $\mu(A_1 \cap A_2)=0$.

Comment: So simple, pitty I didn't see the decomposition of $\mu(A_1)$.

Comment: What happens if $\mu(A_1)=\mu(A_1 \setminus)=+\infty$? In this case, additivity will not give you $\mu(A_1\cup A_2)=0$.

Comment: @Ramiro I forgot to mention that the measure is finite.

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist Then I suggest you should edit the question to include this condition. In fact, you only need the atoms to have finite measure.

Comment: @Ramiro edited.